# Microsoft Azure dll throws an exception in .NET 4.0

Tags: json, serialization, azure

I have developed on EXE project(use for startup task) and use following dlls of Microsoft Azure ,

[image: dlls]

It's work very well in .Net framework 3.5 but in my case i need to use **system.runtime.serialization** to serialize class as json string as per following way

```
 public static string Serialize<T>(T obj)
        {
            System.Runtime.Serialization.Json.DataContractJsonSerializer serializer = new

            System.Runtime.Serialization.Json.DataContractJsonSerializer(obj.GetType());
            MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
            serializer.WriteObject(ms, obj);
            string retVal = Encoding.Default.GetString(ms.ToArray());
            ms.Dispose();
            return retVal;
        }
```

For this i need to change framework to 4.0 but at that time i got exception from Azure dlls
like

**The type initializer for 'Microsoft.WindowsAzure.ServiceRuntime.RoleEnvironment' threw an exception**

I think all Microsoft's dlls are with backward compatibly so what's going wrong in this matter?

I should find another way to serialize to json string?
**OR**
I should to change Azure's dlls to latest version?

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you write a console app in .NET4 and want to use the RoleEnvironment then you’ll get an error:

> The type initializer for ‘Microsoft.WindowsAzure.ServiceRuntime.RoleEnvironment’ threw an exception.

To get around this, just add a “useLegacyV2RuntimeActivationPolicy” to the startup tag generated in the default app.config:

```
<startup useLegacyV2RuntimeActivationPolicy="true">
```

This is because Microsoft.WindowsAzure.ServiceRuntime.dll is a mixed mode assembly. The useLegacyV2RuntimeActivationPolicy attribute is required for referencing any mixed mode assembly, not only the Windows Azure ones.

Answer (score 0):

One thing you might want to check is target framework for your .Net project in Visual Studio. By default when you create a project in VS using .Net framework, it uses ".Net Framework 4 Client Profile". Try changing it to ".Net Framework 4" and see if that helps.

Comment: it is not ".Net Framework 4 Client Profile" i checked that before it is ".Net Framework 4"..